# Find the $x$ and $y$ values that satisfy the constrained optimisation problem.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors

I have the following constrained optimisation problem. We have the following multivariable function:

$$f(x,y) = 4x^2 +4y^2 +3xy -2x +4$$

This function is minimised on the line:

$$0 = \vec n \ (\vec x -\vec p)= \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix} \left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}-2\\3\end{bmatrix} \right)$$

I have to use the Lagrange Multipliers to solve this problem and get the $x$ and $y$ values. I'm not sure how to go about doing this problem because normally I work with $g(x,y)$ as a linear equation which equals a constant (i.e. $x+y=12$). My initial idea was to write down the Lagrange Multipliers, since $f$ is subject to the constraint $g(x,y) = 0$ and simplify the line equation into a polynomial function. The function is as follows:

$$L(x, y, \lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda (g(x,y)-c)$$

The line equation in its equivalent polynomial form:

$$-x+y-5 \equiv y-x = 5$$

Thus $c = 5$ and we have:

$$L(x,y, \lambda) = (4x^2+4y^2 +3xy -2x +4) - \lambda(-x+y-5)$$

From here I can find the gradient of $L$, which would be:

$$\nabla L= \begin{bmatrix}8x+3y-2+ \lambda\\8y +3x-\lambda\\x-y+5\end{bmatrix}$$

I then setup an augmented matrix and reduced it to RREF to solve for $x$ and $y$. The augmented matrix $A$ is as follows:

$$\left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
8 & 3 & 1 & 2\\
3 & 8 & -1 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0 & -5
\end{array}\right] \to  ... \to \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{55}{22}\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{57}{22}\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{27}{2}
\end{array}\right]$$

Therefore, $x = -2.50$ and $y=-2.59$. Hopefully this is correct but again, I'm not a 100% sure because of the line constraint.

Edit: There is a computation error in reducing the augmented matrix (RREF). As stated in the comments and answers, the correct answers are $x=-2.41$ and $y=2.59$.

Comment: Since the constraint is linear, you could simply use it to eliminate one of the variables.  Then you'd just have an ordinary quadratic in one variable, which is easy to minimize.  Good way to check your calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try to do that.

Comment: I Don't find the same values: $x=-53/22$, $y=57/22$ and $\lambda=27/2$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette For the last part I used an online calculator, since it’s 10 steps and the exercise is only worth 1 point. What values did you get?

Comment: I obtened the same matrix as you, and I verified x and y by a direct calculus by replacing y by x+5: $11x^2+53x+104$. The derivative is 0 at $-53/22$.

Comment: Just to say:  your proposed point $(-2.5, -2.59)$ doesn't even satisfy the constraint, $y=x+5$.

Comment: You guys are correct. There was a calculation error in the last part, since I used an online calculator. After doing it again by hand and using the calculator provided by @Siong, I got the same result as "Jean".

Comment: You already have an equation of the form $g(x,y)=0$ for the line, but you might not realize it because you’ve left out the dot product notation. The equation you have is properly written $\vec n\cdot(\vec x-\vec p)=0$. If you expand this, you’ll get a simple linear equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimization problem

$$
\min_{x,y}f(x,y)=4 x^2 + 4 y^2 + 3 x y - 2 x + 4,\ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ g(x,y) = y-x-5=0
$$

can be solved either by substitution of $y = x+5$ into $f(x,y)$ giving the unconstrained.

$$
\min_x f(x,x+5)=4 x^2+3 (x+5) x-2 x+4 (x+5)^2+4
$$

or using the Lagrange multipliers paradigm for the stationary points determination of

$$
L(x,y) = f(x,y)+\lambda g(x,y)
$$

In this case the stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla f +\lambda\nabla g = 0
$$

which means that the functions $f, g$ should be tangent at the solution $\{x^*, y^*\}$ or

$$
\nabla f(x^*, y^*) +\lambda\nabla g(x^*, y^*) = 0
$$

Follows a plot showing first $x\times f(x,x+5)$

[image]

and the tangency at $\{x^*, y^*\}$ in the case of the Lagrangian approach. In black the level curves for $f(x,y)$ in blue $g(x,y)=0$ and in red the solution point $\{-\frac{53}{22},\frac{57}{22}\}$. Note that in both plots, the minimum coordinate $x^* = -\frac{53}{22}$ is the same.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! 

Answer (score 1):

You have made some  computational mistake, perhaps when you used the online calculator:

```
octave:1> rref([8, 3, 1, 2; 3, 8, -1, 0; 1, -1, 0, -5])
ans =

    1.00000    0.00000    0.00000   -2.40909
    0.00000    1.00000    0.00000    2.59091
    0.00000    0.00000    1.00000   13.50000
```

$x=-\frac{53}{2}, y=\frac{57}{22}, \lambda=\frac{27}{2}$.

You can try to use the online rref calculator [here](http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi) to obtain the rational form.

Comment: Yeah it was a computation error at the end. I used the link you provided and got the correct answer. Thank you!